# Is there any method for install the NVPTX on MSYS2 for mingw64 offload to GPU in Win7?

Tags: gpu, msys2, mingw-w64, openacc

I search a lot for the answer above. All the methods were proposed for Linux.
The *mingw-gcc 64-bit* indeed supports the **openACC**. I can call the **runtime API** of **openACC** in the **qtcreator**.

However, when I call:

```
acc_get_device_num(acc_device_nvidia);
```

or

```
acc_get_device_num(acc_device_not_host);
```

the **libgomp** say: no device found.

Or, is there ways to offload using mingw64 in MSYS2 Pacman in Win7?